# Jquery search for a word in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi so i am trying the following:
I want to search for keywords in my text Area

My code works but now i would like to make it search for more than one word.
So if my keyword is 3 words it must look for the 3 word in the text Area i hve no idea how to do this.

so if my keyword is "Mac Air" then it must look for the word "Mac Air" in the textarea

my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label><span class="error error-fields"></span>Focus Keyword</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="keyword" placeholder="Focus Keyword">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label><span class="error-description error-fields"><?php echo $description_error ?></span>Page content</label>
<textarea rows="15" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Page Description"></textarea>  
<p><span class="contentcount"><b>0</b></span> words</p>
</div> 


    $('#description').keyup(function(e){ 

    var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
        w = v.split(/\s/),
        needle = $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase(),
        c = 0;
    for (var i=0,len=w.length;i<len;i++){
        if (w[i] === needle){
            c++;
        }

        if(c > 0 && $('#keyword').val() != ''){
            var value = 'Yes';
            document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'limegreen';
        }else{
            var value = 'No';
            document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'red';
        } 

        checkstatus();  
        extrafunctions();
    }
    $('.content-content').text(value);
    });
```

Comment: Why dont you use `strpos` instead of the `for` loop? It returns `-1` if needle doesn't match in the string, otherwise it's position.

Comment: Never used strpos may you assist me please

Comment: @aly.yousuf7 there is no `strpos` in javascript

Comment: There is `indexOf` for the same purpose in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `String.match`?

```
$('#description').keyup(function (e) {

    var descriptionValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();


    if (descriptionValue.match(new RegExp($('#keyword').val(),'i'))) {
        var value = 'Yes';
        document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'limegreen';
    } else {
        var value = 'No';
        document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'red';
    }

    checkstatus();
    extrafunctions();

    $('.content-content').text(value);
});
```

Comment: Both yours and the above answer works :) thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

I think RegEx is too complicated for this thing. Just use `indexOf()`:

```
$('#description').keyup(function(){ 
  var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var needle = $('#keyword').val().toLowerCase();
  var found = v.indexOf(needle) > -1;

  if (found) {
    value = 'Yes';
    document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'limegreen';
  }else{
    value = 'No';
    document.getElementById("seocontentshow").style.color = 'red';
  } 

  checkstatus();  
  extrafunctions();
  $('.content-content').text(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions make the work really easy here.

```
$('#description').keyup(function() {
        var keyword = $('#keyword').val();
    var text = $('p').text();
    var pattern = new RegExp(keyword, 'gi');
    if(text.match(pattern))
        alert("Keyword found!");
    else
      alert("Keyword wasn't found");
});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c2dxu3p6/

You can read on regular expressions here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Also, here's a demo:
https://regex101.com/r/sV8lC5/1

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer :) helped save so much time. Great Answer

Comment: It's never a good idea to use regular expressions to search for literal strings.

Comment: Exactly, see my answer.